# How to keep non-alphanumeric symbols when tokenizing words in R?

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize

I am using the `tokenizers` package in **R** for tokenizing a text, but non-alphanumeric symbols such as "@" or "&" are lost and I need to keep them. Here is the function I am using:

```
tokenize_ngrams("My number & email address user@website.com", lowercase = FALSE, n = 3, n_min = 1,stopwords = character(), ngram_delim = " ", simplify = FALSE)
```

I know `tokenize_character_shingles` has the `strip_non_alphanum` argument that allows keeping the punctuation, but the tokenization is applied to characters, not words.

Anyone knows how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay to use a different package `ngram`, this has two useful functions that retains those non-alpha

```
> library(ngram)
> print(ngram("My number & email address user@website.com",n = 2), output = 'full')
number & | 1 
email {1} | 

My number | 1 
& {1} | 

address user@website.com | 1 
NULL {1} | 

& email | 1 
address {1} | 

email address | 1 
user@website.com {1} | 

> print(ngram_asweka("My number & email address user@website.com",1,3), output = 'full')
 [1] "My number &"                    "number & email"                
 [3] "& email address"                "email address user@website.com"
 [5] "My number"                      "number &"                      
 [7] "& email"                        "email address"                 
 [9] "address user@website.com"       "My"                            
[11] "number"                         "&"                             
[13] "email"                          "address"                       
[15] "user@website.com"              
>
```

Another beautiful package `quanteda` gives more flexibility with `remove_punct` paramater.

```
> library(quanteda)
> tokenize(text, ngrams = 1:3)
tokenizedTexts from 1 document.
Component 1 :
 [1] "My"                             "number"                        
 [3] "&"                              "email"                         
 [5] "address"                        "user@website.com"              
 [7] "My_number"                      "number_&"                      
 [9] "&_email"                        "email_address"                 
[11] "address_user@website.com"       "My_number_&"                   
[13] "number_&_email"                 "&_email_address"               
[15] "email_address_user@website.com"

>
```